# Red wire in light fixture, no red wire in junction box

Tags: motion-sensor

I just bought a pair of motion activated lights for the side of my garage.  Standard connection turns on the light that triggered with motion. In order to have one light triggered, both lights turn on, the diagram shows  I need to connect the red wire of light one to the red wire of light 2.   The problem is, while the light has red wire, there is no red wire in the junction box.  Could I connect it to the hot  Black wire to have it work the same?  Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are the lights next to each other, or at some distance? If the latter, what is the wiring between them, and what used to be there?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes for each light?

Comment: What is the model # of the light fixtures? That may be key to figuring out how (if possible) to make one trigger the other. Some can, some can't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for wire colors... Al least not for wire function.  Color is decided by the necessity of manufacturing cable. Often we get lucky and the colors in the cable line up with preferred colors for function.

However you can get colored tape and code wires yourself by function.  The first rule of marking wires is **always mark both ends of the same wire at the same time**.

Your setup needs 3 wires besides ground:

- Safety Ground (always green, green/yellow or bare)
- Neutral (always white or gray, though white isn't always neutral)
- Always-hot (preferred: black, any color other than white gray green is legal)
- Switched-hot (preferred: red, ditto)

I am fastidious about using colored wire or marking wires with colored tape, because it makes everything very clear.  My recommendation is to identify the wire that is appropriate, and mark it with red tape.

That said, it may not be possible if the topology of the wiring in your walls does not match the requirement.  Home Depot frequently puts things on the aisle endcap (those are for impulse buys, you know) and people get them home and discover they just won't work with their existing wiring.

### Here's what you do

The two blacks and whites come in two *cables* such as Romex cable.  Cable 1 is the supply cable, and contains supply hot and neutral.  It may or may not come via a switch.

Cable 2 is one of three things: a *switch loop* with the two wires shorted by a switch (probably not); always-hot onward power to receptacles and other loads like a garage door opener; or switched-hot onward power to the other lamp.  We're rooting for that last one.

Start by taking a survey of every load in the house.  Does every half of every receptacle have power?  Does every hardwired thing work, all lights, fans, garage door opener etc.? Sump pump?  If anything does not, take note of that.  This is for a baseline for comparison.

Now, shut off the breaker and split and cap those four wires. Uncap a white/black pair *from the same cable* and hook them up to the light - black to black, white to white.  Cap off lamp red, it will be hot!  Does the light power up?  No? Then that is not the supply cable.  Try the other one.

Now the motion sensor light is working because it is connected to the supply cable.

The other cable is either always-hot onward to other appliances, or switched-hot to the other lamp.  Keep it capped off.  Do the survey again.  What has lost power *now*?  If you find any new things have lost power, you now know that black wire is *always-hot* onward to other loads. Leave it black.

If nothing else has lost power, except the other lamp, then good chance this is onward switched-hot to the other lamp.  Get some red electrical tape and tag the black wire red.

Now you join color to color, with the red-marked black wire going ot red, of course.  Expect 3 neutrals (white).

Comment: Ha you guess it right! I did buy it from Home depot. :D

Comment: Ha you guess it right! I did buy it from Home depot. :D  How do I post a picture? but it is pretty simple,  junction box has 1 copper wire, 2 black wires, and 2 white wires.  And something smaller than the black wires (like the size of bare copper in black)  Right now it is connected with black to black, white to white, copper to copper.  But the motion light turns on individually as motion is triggered.  I would like to have 1 light triggered, both lights turn on.  Am I out of luck with my existing wiring?

Comment: I have a picture of the junction box without the fixture, but the rest is closed, no open wall or anything.  Thank you for the super fast response!

Comment: Is the light operated by a switch also?

Comment: Yes, there is a switch which before  the motion activated lights were installed, it turns both lights on or off.  Now with the motion activated lights installed, I left it "on" and the lights will turn on when motion is triggered.  It then turns off after 5 mins.

Comment: Yes! I I did what you said, and found the 2nd black wire is supposed to be Red switch-wire?).  I connected it with the Red wire from the fixture and it did what it supposed to.  When tha tlight is triggered, both lights turns on. But...

Comment: Question 1:  The 2nd junction box only has one Romex cable 14/3 that was it.  Where can the Red wire of this light goes?

Comment: Question 2:  As of now, the 2nd light's black wire to black wire in junction box, white to white, copper to copper.  But the 2nd light does not turn on with motion anymore.  It is solely relying on the 1st light to be triggered to turn on.  Did I do it right?  In the 1st light, I did connect all 3 white wires (1 from light, and other 2 from the cables)

Comment: After a few tests, I came to realize that the 2nd Romex cable in the 1st light was Romex cable in the 2nd light.Power goes from the 1st light to the  2nd light.  Without it, the 2nd light would not turn on when triggered by motion. Any other way to make 1 light triggered by motion, both lights turn on?  Thank you so much for your help Harper!

Comment: Wait you have a motion sensor at the other light, and you want both to activate?  Ok, slightly different deal.  If you have 14/3 between the lights, then you are correctly wired for this situation. What's more, the colors Do happen to match the functions.  So you don't need to remark any wires at all.  Just join black to black, red to red and white to white.  The 14/3 cable's black wire carries always-hot over there, and the 14/3 cable's red wire carries switched-hot.  Good thing you had 14/3, that is rare.

Comment: Hi Harper, your earlier assumptions were all correct.  The 2nd Romex is "onward switched-hot to the other lamp" I made a typo, it is 14/2, only has black, white, and copper, No red.  Do I connect the Red wire from the 2nd lamp to the black wire 14/2 at the 2nd junction box (which was marked Red on the other end earlier)?  What about the black wire from the lamp?  Leave it cap off?

Comment: @Chris  There is no way to achieve your goal with the wiring that is in the wall, best you can do is have this be a remote light-only.  You could just buy a unit that is just that.  Attach to one and cap of the other, but you need to consult the instructions to see how you handle a "sensor bypass" situation.

Comment: I think I got it, for the 2nd lamp, I need to connect black and red from the lamp to the black in the junction box.  That would create a "1st light triggered, both lights turn on".  But without the additional wire between the 2 lights, I could not make the 2nd light triggered, both light turn on.  Thank you so so much for  your help.   Happy Holidays!

Comment: @chris lol yeah, our messages crossed but you nailed it I think. Good holidays to you too!